# How to check message received and macth string balance at command

Tags: arduino, at-command

```
void loop(){

    Serial.print("AT+CUSD=1,\"*121#\"\r");

    CheckOK();
}

void CheckOK() {

  while (Serial.read() != 'K');  

  delay(100);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringSubstring

```
/*
  String substring()

 Examples of how to use substring in a String

 created 27 July 2010,
 modified 2 Apr 2012
 by Zach Eveland

 http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringSubstring

 This example code is in the public domain.
 */

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // send an intro:
  Serial.println("\n\nString  substring():");
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  // Set up a String:
  String stringOne = "Content-Type: text/html";
  Serial.println(stringOne);

  // substring(index) looks for the substring from the index position to the end:
  if (stringOne.substring(19) == "html") {
    Serial.println("It's an html file");
  }
  // you can also look for a substring in the middle of a string:
  if (stringOne.substring(14, 18) == "text") {
    Serial.println("It's a text-based file");
  }

  // do nothing while true:
  while (true);
}
```